# How can I use color overlay like the one Photoshop has, on SketchApp?

Tags: sketch-app

Title says it all, are there any options on SketchApp like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked for any tutorials?  There seems to be one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeXlr_98y60).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it has.

You can fill a bitmap or object with a color, gradient, pattern or image and change the opacity of it to create an overlaid effect. You can do this in the right hand panel under 'fills'. You can even layer multiple fills for one object.

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/styling/fills/).

Comment: Thanks man! I am still learning :)